# Knuth-Bendix completion algorithm: word problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algorithms, computer-science, computer-algebra-systems

Can someone explain me how to set up an algorithm to find the 12 normal forms of the group $A_4$ by making use of the Knuth-Bendix completion algorithm?

So we have that $RRR=1, SSS=1$ and $RSRS=1$. The goal is to find 12 normal forms (namely the identity, $R$, $RR$, $RS$, etc).

The first step is to look at the given three 'rules' and formulating new rules by trying to combine the old ones. For example, by searching for critical pairs like $RRRSRS$, which can become $SRS$ and $RR$, which gives us the new rule $SRS=RR$. This is straightforward but wouldn't bring us to a solution, because we have to see certain structures. My problem is that I don't know how a computer can see these patterns or can be explained as a step in an algorithm...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean be "see certain structures". Are you asking how Knuth-Bendix is implemented, or do you want to know how to find the complete set of normal forms?

Comment: My question is more about the implementation of Knuth-Bendix. By 'See certain structures' I meant for example: take a look at RRRRRRRSSSSSSRRRRR, apply some rules and see what happens...

Comment: $RRRSRS$ isn't just a string, it is composed of three pieces, $RR(R)SRS$. The algorithm first groups the left two pieces, $(RRR)SRS$ applies the rule for $RRR$ to get $1(SRS) = SRS$ and then simplifies $SRS$ completely using the existing rules in an arbitrary order. Then it does the same to $RR(RSRS)\to RR(1) = RR$ and simplifies $RR$ completely. That ends up with $SRS$ on the one hand and $RR$ on the other. Now the ordering on words is used to decide which is simpler, $SRS$ or $RR$ and the arrow points from the complex to the simple, say $SRS \to RR$.

Comment: Critical pairs are not random, they are formed by the overlaps of the left hand sides of two rules. They are found by considering every pair of left hand sides and checking for overlap (there are some clever string matching algorithms to speed that up, but otherwise it runs is $O(n^2\ell)$ if there are $n$ rules with maximum left-hand-side length $\ell$). Each overlap found is reduced in those two ways, and any differences are handled as explained above.

Comment: OK, so in this way I now have 4 rules and by doing the same argumentation there will show up some more rules. But will this lead to the 12 normal forms?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you use “shortlex” to decide which is simpler, it leads to 8 rules (5 new ones, 1 redundant old one). Then there are ways to enumerate the normal forms. The crudest is just to take all the known normal forms (like $R$ and $S$), and multiply them by the generators $R$ and $S$, only keeping forms that are already simplest.

Comment: You can code this up without too much trouble. I wrote a silly javascript version at one point, but apparently SVG no longer works (it made cool directed graphs of the possible reduction strategies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Knuth-Bendix program, and I ran it on this example. It completed with the $7$ rewrite rules:

```
     [R^3 -> 1],
     [S^3 -> 1],
     [S*R*S -> R^2],
     [R*S*R -> S^2],
     [R^2*S^2 -> S*R],
     [S^2*R^2 -> R*S],
     [S*R^2*S -> R*S^2*R]
```

The $12$ normal form words are:

```
 1, R, R^2, R^2*S, R*S, R*S^2, R*S^2*R, S, S*R, S*R^2, S^2, S^2*R
```

Comment: The problem is that I still don't know how this algorithm works/can be implemented

Comment: You could try the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Bendix_completion_algorithm

Comment: @abc I found this a very readable explanation: http://haskellformaths.blogspot.com/2010/05/string-rewriting-and-knuth-bendix.html. Its principal example is a normalization just like yours except for $D_8$ instead of for $A_4$.